# How to make the first letter of a word uppercase?

Tags: php, string

I have this word:

```
katii
```

But I want the first character in uppercase `K`. How can I do this?

Comment: Use ucfirst function http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ucfirst.php

Comment: Try using ucfirst();

Comment: Start google ....

Answer (score 0):

Use function [usfirst](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php)

```
  string ucfirst ( string $str )
```

Comment: While I'm aware that answering is completely up to the individual user, I really do wish people would stop answering questions like this as it has a negative effect of making people believe they will get a answer without having to do any form of research, and not care about SO's rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below as prescribed by php.net

```
<?php
$foo = 'hello world!';
$foo = ucfirst($foo);             // Hello world!

$bar = 'HELLO WORLD!';
$bar = ucfirst($bar);             // HELLO WORLD!
$bar = ucfirst(strtolower($bar)); // Hello world!
?>
```

Comment: I need Just first of the worn not all the word just H i want to get not all the word how can i do that thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
$upper = strtoupper(substr('katii', 0, 1)); //K
```

You should make your question a little clearer in future, though.